# sql lite dynamic Query for sqllite-pcl xamarin forms

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, record

i  have created dynamic tables in Xamarin forms by using SQLite queries

string cmdStr="CREATE TABLE  Mytable ....";
i am able to create table using

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlitConnection);
command.CommandText = cmdStr;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the above code is working fine ,i am able to save data to sql lite db

i am unable to get data from db using  command.ExecuteQuery() using command string as "select * from Mytable". as seen in screenshot i am unable to fetch content from dynamic tables,please suggest any alternatives

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phse0.png)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!

Answer (score -1):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong - you are not specifying a Type argument T.  The correct syntax is

```
List<T> results = command.ExecuteQuery<T>();
```

where `T` is the name of the class you are mapping the results to

Comment: actually i am not using class is it possible without adding class

Comment: the whole point of using sqlite-net is the ORM it provides.